# Retrieving array with mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I'm trying to convert some old php code that used mysql to using mysqli,

the code I've updated to is:

```
function mysql_fetch_full_result_array($result){
global $dbc;

    $table_result=array();
    $r=0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $arr_row=array();
        $c=0;
        while ($c < mysqli_num_fields($result)) {       
            $col = mysqli_fetch_field($result);   
            $arr_row[$col -> name] = $row[$col -> name];           
            $c++;
        }   
        $table_result[$r] = $arr_row;
        $r++;
    }   
    return $table_result;
}
```

However, after the first row, it's only outputting null for every value as seen here, i'm sure I'm not incrementing something but I'm not sure where or how at this point:

```
{"DOMAIN.COM":[{"image":"http:\/\/DOMAIN.COM\/photos\/grid_logo.jpg","source":"logo","user":"","printed":"","note":""},{"image":"http:\/\/DOMAIN.COM\/photos\/grid_block.jpg","source":"block","user":"","printed":"","note":""},{"image":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/BlNvdcrCAAAlz8-.jpg","source":"twitter","user":"ObserveMeditate","printed":"0","note":"RT @IMSEngage: Moby (@thelittleidiot) sits down with the legendary @DAVID_LYNCH this Wednesday: http:\/\/t.co\/PMn9EHQVcp #IMSEngage http:\/\/t.\u2026"},{"image":null,"source":null,"user":null,"printed":null,"note":null},{"image":null,"source":null,"user":null,"printed":null,"note":null},{"image":null,"source":null,"user":null,"printed":null,"note":null},{"image":null,"source":null,"user":null,"printed":null,"note":null},{"image":null,"source":null,"user":null,"printed":null,"note":null},{"image":null,"source":null,"user":null,"printed":null,"note":null},{"image":null,"source":null,"user":null,"printed":null,"note":null},{"image":null,"source":null,"user":null,"printed":null,"note":null},{"image":null,"source":null,"user":null,"printed":null,"note":null},{"image":null,"source":null,"user":null,"printed":null,"note":null},{"image":null,"source":null,"user":null,"printed":null,"note":null},{"image":null,"source":null,"user":null,"printed":null,"note":null},{"image":null,"source":null,"user":null,"printed":null,"note":null},{"image":null,"source":null,"user":null,"printed":null,"note":null},{"image":null,"source":null,"user":null,"printed":null,"note":null},{"image":null,"source":null,"user":null,"printed":null,"note":null},{"image":null,"source":null,"user":null,"printed":null,"note":null},{"image":null,"source":null,"user":null,"printed":null,"note":null},{"image":null,"source":null,"user":null,"printed":null,"note":null},{"image":null,"source":null,"user":null,"printed":null,"note":null}]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that what you are attempting to do is the same as this (except with a lot of extraneous code):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $table_result[] = $row;
}   
return $table_result;
```

Or maybe:

```
while($row[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { }   
return $row;
```

Or even just:

```
$all_rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC); //may still be server dependent
```

Comment: Thank you. I used your first one and that's all I needed. I appreciate it.

Comment: If available i would use `mysqli_fetch_all`.